# c++ как брать данные из интернета?

Tags: c++

Скорее всего вопрос поставлен некорректно, но суть такова. Хочу написать небольшое приложение. Есть сайт, на нем ежедневно обновляются данные. Запускаешь прогу, она висит в трее и раз в день берет эти данные сайта, записывает в блокнот, а при выходе за границы определенных данных подает звуковой сигнал. Проблема заключается в том, что я не знаю как взять эти данные с сайта. Походу я из тех одаренных, которые не умеют гуглить)) Буду признателен за помощь.

Comment: Можно больше конкретики? Слишком рано расплывчатые определения

Comment: Вас интересует [HTTP-протокол](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP).

Comment: @Vladimir ок, еще проще. Программа берет точное время с сайта https://time100.ru/ и записывает в тхт. Какой код? Как заставить программу взять данные с сайта? Не знаю куда проще.

Comment: Я четко описал вам, что вам нужно.

Comment: Если раз в день, то посмотрите на [wget](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wget) и напишите что-то такое --  `system("wget -O Result https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/818288 > Logfile 2>&1");`

Comment: @Vladimir, он спрашивает, как послать http-запрос - вроде всё ясно?

Answer (score 2):

То что вы хотите, называется «Парсинг HTTP данных», вам нужно каждый раз делать запрос по протоколу **HTTP**, получать в ответ данные, скорее всего там будет **HTML**, далее вы должны правильно эти данные распределить, и записать в файл. Удобнее всего в данный момент делать **HTTP** запросы с помощью почти стандартной библиотеки **Boost::Asiо**. Правда она весит много... Но в следующий раз да, советую вам попробовать сформулировать поисковый запрос.

Comment: Может всё-таки asio?

Comment: Да, вы правы, опечатка.